# Which is correct 'Researches are going on' or 'Research is being carried out'?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, countability

Researches is a verb. Can it be used in a context like:

> *Researches are going on*

OR should it be

> *Research is being carried out*?

Which is syntactically and semantically correct English?

Comment: "Research" can be a noun or a verb. When we add "es" to it, it certainly becomes a noun. But it cannot be used in the plural ("researches"), so you cannot use it. You can say "**research projects** are being performed" (here the word "research" would serve as an adjective). The noun "research" is uncountable, that's why you can't add **es** to the end of it.

Comment: Lots to say about this question. I've done some research  on this particular noun in the past, its history is quite interesting.

Comment: @CowperKettle "When we add "es" to it, it certainly becomes a noun." Huh?: `Joe researches genetics.`

Comment: @HWalters - yes, I under-researched the issue. I meant it becomes a noun in the sentence "Researches are going on".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In American English, "Researches are going on" is grammatically incorrect.

As a noun, "research" is not countable.  If Americans want to talk about more than one research project, they talk about "research projects", not "researches".

As a verb, "research" is conjugated the usual way.  In the present tense:

```
I research.     We research.
You research.   You research.
He researches.  They research.
```

Because "research" is a formal word, "You research" is much, much more common than "Y'all research".

Comment: This also applies in British English

Answer (score 3):

Both of your suggested formulations would appear unusual. The first is grammatically incorrect, the second is clunky. Both are in the passive voice.

I would suggest "We/they are researching..." or "Research into X is ongoing" as possible alternatives but without knowing the context of your statement I cannot say what the correct phrasing is.